# Is there any event to indicate that all dependency properties were loaded?

Tags: c#, silverlight, binding, user-controls

I have a silverlight user control with three dependency properties. All properties are bound successfully and they have correct values. Values for these properties are loaded asynchronously in parent control so I don't know the sequence of my properties' binding. I need to load some entities when all properties of my control have been loaded. Is there any elegant solution to solve this issue. I don't want to use a hack creating a private field or something like it. Load event is fired before all bindings, because as I said my properties load asynchronously.

Here is an example:

```
<namespace:MyControl Prop1="{Binding ParentProp1}" Prop2="{Binding ParentProp2}" Prop3="{Binding ParentProp3}" />
```

Comment: As your question says "Is there any event to indicate that all dependency properties were loaded?" Answer is NO!

Answer (score 0):

Create your own event and call it when all your properties are initialized.
You can determine that all your properties are correctly initialized by implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged` in your control and then subscribing to the `OnPropertyChanged` event and checking that all properties are initialized. There you can fire your event to tell any subscriber that initialization was finished.

[Implement INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743695%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
[C# Events Guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743695%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)